# excel countif filtered by style

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

I have an Excel spreadsheet and I'm trying to count rows in a column based on a style applied to some cells in the column. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not really. You could use Visual Basic to access cell formatting properties but most inbuilt functions that you would type into a cell focus on the cell contents, not the formatting.

If your styles have different shading colours then you can use the following method.

Step 1: Convert your range to a list and then adding a total row showing COUNT

[image]

Step 2: Apply a colour filter (should work on Excel 2007 and later):

[image]

Done: The COUNT total will show the filtered number of rows.

[image]

Comment: I would have preferred an answer that said, "of course you can! here's how to do it!" but, alas, you're probably right. There's no way to do what I want without using VB. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use VBA for that:

```
Function CountStyle(CellRange)
   Dim Item As Range, Total As Long
   For Each Item In CellRange
      ' Check to see if the cell is formatted as Style = "Neutral"
      If Item.Style = "Neutral" Then
         Total = Total + 1
      End If
   Next Item
   CountStyle = Total
End Function
```

Taken from [here](http://www.office-loesung.de/ftopic412600_0_0_asc.php).

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to start the Visual Basic editor.
2. Insert > Module
3. Insert above code
4. Go to Excel and choose the cell, where the result should be in. Write e.g. `=CountStyle (B4:B23)`

Now you have count all cells with the style `Neutral`. I've created three functions for neutral, good, bad. This looks like:

```
Function CountStyleGood(CellRange)
   Dim Item As Range, Total As Long
   For Each Item In CellRange
      ' Check to see if the cell is formatted as Style = "Good"
      If Item.Style = "Good" Then
         Total = Total + 1
      End If
   Next Item
   CountStyleGood = Total
End Function
```

Wit `=CountStyleGood(B4:B23)` you get the result. As name of the style I've used the name displayed in the ribbon.